# Apache Mod-Rewrite .htaccess segment swapping

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a .htaccess file that can take a url like this:

```
http://example.com/api/module/something/something/something......
```

The url can have n amount of segments, and module is variable, what I need to accomplish is rewrite it to:

```
http://example.com/module/api/something/something/something......
```

Currently this is accomplished with the following PHP code, but this isn't an elegant solution

```
$pieces = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$pieces = array_slice($pieces, 2, count($pieces)-2,false);
$module = $pieces[0];
unset($pieces[0]);
$end = implode('/', $pieces);
header('Location: /'.$module.'/api/'.$end);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the htaccess file in your document root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/api/$2 [L]
```

If you want it to actually redirect like it is doing in your PHP code, replace the `L` with a `R=301` in the brackets.

Comment: Thanks, please see my edits I forgot to mention module is variable.

Comment: this doesn't exactly work  originial http://example.com/api/module/segment1/segment2
rewritten
http://example.com/module/segment1/api/segment2

Comment: @stefan not sure how that's possible, since `([^/]+)` matches any character that *isn't* a **/**, so not sure how it managed to match `module/segment1`.